# Overriding BaseMediaAdmin with sonataMediaBundle

Tags: symfony, overriding, sonata-admin

I am looking for to override the BaseMediaBundle to custom for exemple the function "configureListFields".

I already override the controller of this bundle, but not the BaseMediaAdmin.

The problem with this code is the entity "Media" disapear of my dashboard !

*//In my services.xml :*

```
<service id="sonata.media.admin.media" class="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin\MediaAdmin">
        <tag name="sonata.media.admin" manager_type="orm" group="Gestion des médias"
            label="Média" />
        <argument />
        <argument>Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media</argument>
        <argument>Application\SonataMediaBundle:MediaAdmin</argument>
        <call method="setTranslationDomain">
            <argument>SonataMediaBundle</argument>
        </call>
    </service>
```

*//In my Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin\MediaAdmin*

```
namespace Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;
use Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider\Pool;
use Sonata\MediaBundle\Form\DataTransformer\ProviderDataTransformer;

use Knp\Menu\ItemInterface as MenuItemInterface;

use Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin\BaseMediaAdmin as BaseMediaAdmin;


class MediaAdmin extends BaseMediaAdmin
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
//            ->add('image', 'string', array('template' => 'SonataMediaBundle:MediaAdmin:list_image.html.twig'))
            ->add('custom', 'string', array('template' => 'SonataMediaBundle:MediaAdmin:list_custom.html.twig'))
            ->add('enabled', 'boolean', array('editable' => true))
            ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
                'actions' => array(
                    'view' => array(),
                    'edit' => array(),
                    'delete' => array(),
                )
            ))
        ;
    }

}
```

If someone has an idea ? Thx for your help

Comment: No one has got the same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Sonata Admin extensions](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/extensions.html).